# Why doesn't the inner element transition?

Tags: css

When changing both the `display` and `opacity` properties at the same time, with a transition applied to `opacity`, I expect that the transition will be visible so long as the element does not have `display: none`. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

See the following snippet, and observe that when the outer element is hovered, the inner element appears instantly:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 2.5rem;
  background: cyan;

  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.outer:hover .inner {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=outer>
  Hover me
  <div class=inner></div>
</div>
```

Now, I already know that [display is not an animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#formal_definition). Therefore, even if I *had* included it in the transition, I would expect it to apply instantly on hover regardless.

However, I know that `opacity` *is* an animatable property. Therefore, when hovered, the inner element has `display: block` and the `opacity` property **should** smoothly transition from 0 to 1. **It doesn't.**

(When unhovered, the inner element gets `display: none` immediately, so there's no time for a transition in the other direction.)

Why doesn't the inner element transition?

Comment: Interestingly, substituting `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` in place of `display:none` and `display: block` *does* allow the transition to occur.  I don't have an explanation for the different behavior of `display`.

Comment: Not confident enough to post this as an official answer but I believe it's because `display: none` actually removes the element from the document formatting structure; that's probably what interferes with concurrent animations. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display.  That'd explain the difference compared to `visibility`, which doesn't remove the elements, just makes them invisible

Comment: Ah, in that case perhaps so long as the element has `display: none` it doesn't exist at all - so it *never* has `opacity: 0`, so there's no valid transition? I think you might be on to something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#animations),

> Setting the display property to none will terminate any running
> animation applied to the element and its descendants. If an element
> has a display of none, updating display to a value other than none
> will start all animations applied to the element by the animation-name
> property, as well as all animations applied to descendants with
> display other than none.

Keyframe animations (using `animation-name`) can therefore transition while using `display:none`:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 2.5rem;
  background: cyan;
  animation-name: makeinvisible;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.outer:hover .inner {
  animation-name: makevisible;
  animation-duration: 1s;

}

@keyframes makevisible {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes makeinvisible {
  0% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=outer>
  Hover me
  <div class=inner></div>
</div>
```

...but for `transition`s, the fact that `display: none` removes the element from the document formatting structure appears to block the transition that would otherwise occur when `display:block` is set.

The CSS working group [discussed changing this to allow animating `display` in 2022](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6429#issuecomment-1332439874).

In the meantime, you can simply omit the `display` declarations altogether and let `opacity` run things, or else use `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` which makes elements invisible without removing them from the document render, so doesn't exhibit this behavior.